# Trying to remove odd and even numbers

Tags: c#, for-loop, listbox

I have a list box with some buttons. Right now I am trying to get it to find odd and even numbers in the list and remove them when the button is clicked. but it's removing the odd and even position in the list.

Here is my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Remove Even Numbers
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Int32.Parse(listBox1.Items[i]) % 2 == 0)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.Items[i]);
        }
    }              
}


private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Remove Odd Numbers*
{
   for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
       if (Int32.Parse(listBox1.Items[i] % 2 == 1))
        {
         listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.Items[i]);
        }
    }


The program should be able to find the odd or even numbers in the list and remove them when the button is pressed.
```

Comment: You are modifying the items collection during iterating over this collection. This almost always will not work as expected.

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code - currently there is extra code in the post and no input data for the sample. Also replace usage of ancient obsolete `ArrayList` class with `List<int>` class. If reading the duplicate I selected (I did that based on the *task* you have, not the partial code in the post) and creating complete sample does not help - please ping me after updating the post and I likely will re-open it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I believe I have adjusted the code to be more readable. let me know if this is acceptable

Comment: The problem occurs because as you delete an item, the items below that point shift up to "fill the hole", but your `i` variable still increases causing it to skip an item. For instance, if the value at index 3 was deleted, the value that was previously at index 4 gets moved into index position 3. Afterwar the deletion and shift, though, your `for` loop moves the `i` variable from 3 to 4, causing it to skip the item that was just moved to index 3.  You could "fix" this by **decrementing** `i` whenever you delete an item; `i--`. This way the for loop will add 1 back and keep the "current index".